# Within vs target pointcut designator in Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring-aop

I couldn't understand different between within and target pointcut designator.

Look at the example:

```
@Component
public interface Icamera {
    public void snap() throws Exception;
}

@Component
class Camera implements Icamera {
    public void snap() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("SNAP!");
    }
}

@Aspect
@Component
public class Logger {

    **@Pointcut("within(com.test.aop.Icamera)")**
    public void cameraSnap() {
    }

    @Before("cameraSnap()")
    public void beforeAdvice() {
        System.out.println("Before advice ...");
    }

    @After("cameraSnap()")
    public void afterAdvice() {
        System.out.println("After advice ...");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        Icamera camera = context.getBean(Icamera.class);
        camera.snap();
    }

}
```

The output is:
SNAP!
but when you use target instead of within, the output is:
Before advice ...
SNAP!
After advice ...

Answer (score 0):

Spring documentation isn't particularly clear but they provide full reference of supported AspectJ pointcut types: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts

In case of your example

> *within* - limits matching to join points within certain types (simply the execution of a method declared within a matching type when using Spring AOP)

So the type of the actual `@Component` receiving the method call should match the selector in `within`. It will intercept the call if you specify bean class name

```
@Pointcut("within(com.test.aop.Camera)")
```

package selector

```
@Pointcut("within(com.test.aop.*)")
```

or some parent package with sub-packages selector

```
@Pointcut("within(com.test..*)")
```

> *target* - limits matching to join points (the execution of methods when using Spring AOP) where the target object (application object being proxied) is an instance of the given type

As the documentation suggests applies to method calls on all beans where `<beanClass> instanceof <targetType>` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: `targetType` would be the type specified inside `target()`, right?

Comment: Yes. Something like `target(com.xyz.service.AccountService)`